# GridView View Recycling in AppWidget

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I'm using a GridView in an AppWidget, and I'm having a problem with its view recycling.  [RemoteViewsFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory) doesn't have any way to deal with recycled views as far as I can tell, the `getView` method only has an index, no convertView to use.  So, when my GridView recycles a view, it retains all the same data as the original occurrence of it, and this is wrong.  Is there any way I can disable the view recycling, or edit the recycled view to replace its data?

At first I thought to just return a different viewtype for each index, but RemoteViewsFactory hides that too, so I can't do that either!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out.  When I'm creating the list of views that will populate the adapter used by the GridView, I just clear all views before putting the data into it.  I have no idea why it works, but it seems to.

```
 RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews( _context.getPackageName(), R.id.base_view );
 view.removeAllViews( R.id.day_box );
```